If you use IAM to manage access to RDS postgress database, how do you authenticate with SQL tools like dbeaver free?
We have 60+ RDS databases, and adding and removing users my hand is tedious, and users cant (easily) change passwords.
If we use IAM to manage users, how would we use tools like DBeaver (free edition) which don't support IAM directly?  Also, we have to use an SSH tunnel as the RDS instances are not public.
Is it possible for some RDS database users to authenticate with IAM (e.g. services which have necessary IAM connection authentication libraries), and some to use plain old Postgres authentication (read only user perhaps).  Then one could have both worlds.  However, this post: Use IAM authentication AND a regular password to access AWS RDS implies that with postgres and IAM, you cant then have normal users, which makes connecting to the DB presumably impossible for tools which dont support IAM.  DBeaver team does support IAM, but at $400 per dev, its completely out of our price budget just to be able to connect unfortunately.  Maybe Heidi SQL or other tools support IAM?

What environment are you using? Can you leverage domain accounts via AWS Directory Services?


Is it possible for some RDS database users to authenticate with IAM (e.g. services which have necessary IAM connection authentication libraries), and some to use plain old Postgres authentication (read only user perhaps).

Sort of! Technically yes but probably not how you're imagining! Keep in mind that a database user and an IAM user are different things. When you use IAM to get an auth token, you get that token for a specific database user. So, "joe@company.com" (the IAM user) could get a token for "joe" (the postgres user), or "generic_support_engineer" (another postgres user). You've got some options about how you handle this. It may be reasonable for you to have one shared account in each of your 60 databases have the rds_iam role in postgres, and then 15 IAM Users who all have permission via policy to get a token to auth as that user. Then when you add/remove a human, you're just adding that policy to that iam user. Add permission granularity by creating more purpose-specific shared users.
So while you can't make one specific database user work with both password and iam, you can support both scenarios.
Before you get too deep into considering how to support both, though, take note that you can also use IAM authentication with any tool even if it doesn't directly support it - the aws cli command rds generate-db-auth-token outputs a token, which is basically just a temporary expiring password.
Example:

I am using the aws cli logged in as joe@company.com.
I want to connect to $RDSHOST in a support capacity where i need read only access.
You (the admin) set up a database user named support_readonly for this purpose and joe@company.com is allowed to use it.

aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $RDSHOST \ 
  --port 5432 \ 
  --region us-east-1 \ 
  --username support_readonly

This command outputs a giant string (the token), which is basically just a temporary password. Then I can use any postgres client: for the username i enter "support_readonly" and for password I paste in that token.  These tokens expire in 15min, so if I make a new connection in half an hour, I'll need to generate a new token, but if my connection is alive, it stays valid.
Again, this all requires that you have an IAM policy that allows you to get a token for this user for this database instance, and that you created some_postgres_user with the role rds_iam, but that's all covered in this repost.aws knowledge center post: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-connect-using-iam.
Additionally, you'll find that some clients have "generic" support for retrieving a password.. for example, Postico allows you to run an arbitrary script at connection time to set connection parameters, and the jetbrains ide suite has an aws-specific plugin and also a generic plugin that does similar.  How you pull this off probably depends a lot on what your users need.

Thanks, this is very useful.  using aws cli each time you want to connect is not really an option for us, as we have 60+ dbs , and we connect to them frequently and for short periods, plus the fact that several of us have never managed to get the aws cli to work (we dont use IAM directly, we have to go through AD which gives us access to keys, but there is no actual user in IAM).  Looks like we will have to stick to plain old postgres authentication.  Looks like the answer to my question is actually no, i.e. if you use IAM you cannot use posgres native at same time.
